# Removing part of string before a sub-string and its first occurrence

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a text output like:

```
str <- '=== AAAA === B§BBB === remove === remove1 === remove2 === AAAA === AAAA'
```

I would like to remove all the substring between the ===remove (included) and its first next ocurrency:

```
str_2 <- '=== AAAA === B§BBB === AAAA === AAAA'
```

I tried in `gsub()`:

```
gsub("=== B§BBB*.*=== AAAA","",str))
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to the updated question**

```
str <- '=== AAAA === B§BBB === remove === remove1 === remove2 === AAAA === AAAA'
sub("(?:\\s*===\\s*remove\\S*)+","",str)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/P4bC3f) and an [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/igjNdr/1).

The pattern matches 1+ consecutive occurrences of

- `\\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `===` - a substring
- `\\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `remove` - a literal substring
- `\\S*` - 0 or more chars other than whitespace

**Answer to the original question**

You may use

```
sub("=== remove.*?(\n\\s*?=== AAAA)","\\1",str)
```

**Details**

- `=== remove` - matches a literal substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(\n\\s*?=== AAAA)` - Group 1 (later referenced with `\1` from the replacement pattern): a newline, 0+ whitespaces (`\s*?`), `=== AAAA` substring.

An alternative PCRE regex can also be used:

```
sub("(?m)(?:(?:^|\\R)\\h*===\\h*remove)+","",str, perl=TRUE)
```

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `^` now matches start of lines
- `(?:(?:^|\\R)\\h*===\\h*remove)+` - 1+ occurrences of

  - `(?:^|\\R)` - start of line or a line break
  - `\\h*===\\h*` - a `===` substring wrapped with 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `remove` - a literal substring.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have a newline in this string. Editing my question @Wiktor

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `stringi` package.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(str, " === remove", "")

[1] "=== AAAA === B§BBB === AAAA === AAAA"
```

Comment: edited the question, "remove" string may also vary to "remove1" or whatever @milan. sorry about that.